# Suppose that f(0) = f(1) = 0 and x ∈ (0, 1). Prove that there exists c ∈ (0, 1) such that f'(c) = f(x).

Tags: calculus

Let f be a function continuous on [0,1] and differentiable on (0,1)

My attempt:

I have tried solving using Rolle's theorem for f'(c) = 0

`I let c<x then by Mean Value Theorem,`
f'(c) = (f(x)-f(0))/(x-0) = f(x)/x
since f'(c) = 0, f(x) = 0
Hence f'(c) = f(x)

Similarly, I let c>x
and by Mean Value Theorem again,
f'(c) = (f(1)-f(x))/(1-x)
      = f(x)/(1-x)
since f'(c) = 0, f(x) = 0
Hence f'(c) = f(x)

I feel like this proof is wrong because I don't know how to continue with the case where c=x

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)=0$, Rolle's theorem implies $f'(c)=0$, for some $c\in(0,1)$.

Now suppose $f(x)\ne0$, let
$$F(t)=f(t)-tf(x),t\in[0,1],$$
then $$F(0)=0,F(x)=(1-x)f(x),F(1)=-f(x),$$
and $$F(x)\cdot F(1)=(x-1)f^2(x)<0,$$
so, by Intermediate value theorem, there exists $x_0\in(x,1)$ such that
$$F(x_0)=0.$$
Consider function $F(x),x\in[0,x_0]$, we know
$$F(0)=F(x_0)=0,$$
so Rolle's theorem implies 
$$F'(c)=0$$
for some $c\in(0,x_0)\subset(0,1)$.
Due to 
$$F'(t)=f'(t)-f(x)$$
we know there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that 
$$f'(c)=f(x).$$